# ExtJs 3.4 поменять разделитель данных приходящих на бэк

Tags: javascript, php, extjs, rpc

Есть поле множественного выбора.

```
xtype: 'superboxselect',
fieldLabel: 'товар',
name: 'sell_items',
store: sellItems(),
```

При выборе нескольких товаров и отправки запроса на бэк, входящие данные выглядят следующим образом:

```
sell_items = 'носки,трусы,шапка,варежки'
```

Есть ли какой-то параметр для поля (или для стора возможно) с помощью которого можно задать произвольный разделитель? Необходимо заменить запятую.

Comment: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.ux.form.MultiSelect.html#cfg-delimiter

Comment: увы в extJs 3.4 нет такого.

Answer (score 0):

В superboxselect разделитель называется valueDelimiter.

```
valueDelimiter: '//',
```